# How to write LINQ query as one query?

Tags: linq

I have the following query that groups locations and the average item cost and I would like to write it as one query but I cannot figure out the syntax. What LINQ do I need to do this? I have tried writing it different ways but the syntax is not correct.

```
        var joinedData =
            from r in shops
            join i in items on r.shopId equals i.shopId 
            select new
            {
                Region = r.Location,
                ItemCost = i.ItemCost
            };

        var AverageCostByLocation = joinedData
            .GroupBy(m => new { m.Location})
            .Select(m => new
            {
                Location= m.Key.Location,
                AverageItemCost = m.Average(x => x.ItemCost)
            });
```

Comment: Why can't you just join them after `select new... ` statement ? Put first expression in parenthesis and follow it by `.GroupBy` and with the rest of your query. Or, wait, is it working ?

Comment: @Fabjan thank you for your comment. I was able to join the two queries using your suggestion. If you add your comment as an answer I can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you put first expression in parenthesis it should allow to join both expressions as they are. Also I'd probably get rid of second anonymous type for perfomance reasons (the `new { m.Location}` line is redundant, you might want to use `.Key` instead) :

```
var AverageCostByLocation =
        (from r in shops
        join i in items on r.shopId equals i.shopId 
        select new
        {
            Region = r.Location,
            ItemCost = i.ItemCost
        })
        .GroupBy(m => m.Location)
        .Select(m => new
        {
            Location= m.Key,
            AverageItemCost = m.Average(x => x.ItemCost)
        });
```